# Учёт регистра при редиректах через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Настроил верхний в нижний регистр. Но редиректит и фотографии.
Папка - /images/
Как поставить условие, чтобы не переводило в нижний регистр?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] [OR] !images
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Что то вроде такого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/images\/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !rewrite\-strtolower\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

UPD. Можно тогда вариант основанный на расширениях картинок попробовать

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Comment: http://www.orto-line.com.ua/images/thumbnails/85/127/detailed/9/PT_0471.jpg

Comment: Редиректит всё равно в нижний регистр картинку.

Comment: Пока что отключил. А то по сайту везде миниатюры битые вылазят.

Comment: @СтаниславКучер, строку `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/images\/ [NC]` замените на `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]`, а `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !rewrite\-strtolower\.php [NC]` удалите.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/12MZ1Mxs4PZ7pA

Comment: http://joxi.ru/RmzbXWQfW48OYm

Comment: @СтаниславКучер, другой вариант предложил

Comment: Спасибо!) Помогло!)